# Searching data from database using checkbox list ASP.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, checkboxlist

I have checkbox list populated form a table in a SQL database, i want to build a SQL query return results from another table related to first table  depending on selected checkbox list values . the problem is that its not working properly,  , I think that the query need to include all selected values not one.
here is my code: thank you in advance for your help

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DS.DiseaseID, D.DiseaseName from DiseasesSymptoms DS inner join  Diseases D on DS.DiseaseID = D.DiseaseID  where SymptomID='" + CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue + "'", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You should read up on SQL Injection attacks, right now your code is _very_ vulnerable to one

Answer (score 0):

Mohammad you are missing basic concept Executenonquery is generally using for insert /update or delete not for fetching the record.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DS.DiseaseID, D.DiseaseName from DiseasesSymptoms DS inner join  Diseases D on DS.DiseaseID = D.DiseaseID  where SymptomID='" + CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue + "'", con);


SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```